Pyinstaller build for Kivy and KivyMD
I have problem when building the exe file where the MDFloatButton disable is not working after build exe, but it is working as usual before build.
for btn in self.ids.values():  # Loop through all widgets in self.ids
    if isinstance(btn, MDFloatingActionButton) and btn != button_instance:
        btn.disabled = True

this is the snipped code for button disable after click, but when i build , this function is not working, it does not disable the button after i click.
Im using:

Python 3.9.0
KivyMD 1.0.1
Pyinstaller 6.0.0

block_cipher = None
from kivy_deps import sdl2, glew
from kivymd import hooks_path as kivymd_hooks_path

a = Analysis(
    ['Main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('login.kv', '.')],
    hiddenimports=['kivymd.icon_definitions.icon_definitions', 'kivymd.uix.button', 'kivy.properties'],
    hookspath=[kivymd_hooks_path],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
    name='Main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,   
)


The reason is for the class that is a button, in the code:
for btn in self.ids.values():  # Loop through all widgets in self.ids
    if isinstance(btn, MDFloatingActionButton) and btn != button_instance:
        btn.disabled = True

The name btn is obtaining the ids of the widgets and later assigning the disabled=True value, however at this point, in the kivymd lifecycle, the button is receiving a value outside the GUI of kivymd, to make sure the button widget can accept this value and represent it in the GUI, you can do this:
Define a function in the app:
def enable_disable_the_button(self,tell_me_the_widget,field1,field2):
    the_button_is=tell_me_the_widget #this one comes from the GUI, gets stored here, meaning this variable is connected to the GUI, if I apply a change in its attributes it should work:
    #I want this button to:
    if len(field1.text)>0 and len(field2.text)>0:
        the_button_is.disabled=False
        return 0
    if len(field1.text)==0 or len(field2.text)==0:
        the_button_is.disabled=True
        return 0

Later you can use it or implement it from Kivy Lang:
Screen:
    ScreenManager:
        id: MainActivity

        Screen:
            id: SecondActivity
            name: "main"
            MDCard:
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 300, 400
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
                elevation: 10
                padding: 25
                spacing: 25
                orientation: 'vertical'

                MDLabel:
                    id: welcome_label
                    text: "This is MJ"
                    font_size: 30
                    halign: 'center'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    padding_y: 15
                    

                MDTextFieldRound:
                    id: user
                    hint_text: "username"
                    icon_right: "account"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: 200
                    font_size: 18
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    on_text: app.enable_disable_the_button(root.ids.floatingbutton2024,root.ids.user,root.ids.password)

                MDTextFieldRound:
                    id: password
                    hint_text: "password"
                    icon_right: "eye-off"
                    size_hint_x: None
                    width: 200
                    font_size: 18
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    password: True
                    on_text: app.enable_disable_the_button(root.ids.floatingbutton2024,root.ids.user,root.ids.password)


                MDFloatingActionButton:
                    id: floatingbutton2024
                    icon: "login"
                    md_bg_color: [0,0,.5,1]
                    md_text_color: [1,1,1,1]
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                    disabled: True

                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "Clear fields"
                    font_size: 12
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

And the result is, if nothing is written in both, the button stays disabled, if both fields are filled, the button stays enabled:

While typing on both:

